# Move wordpress from test environent to production environment and keep posts

Tags: wordpress, test-environments

I want to move my wordpress dir form my development environment to my production environent. The thing is that my production environment is an ongoing blog were I want to use the posts thats on my blog and not the fake posts on my development environment.

So I want to use my old database and not the one I have in my development environment. Is this possible? And how do I do this?

Comment: It sounds like you just need to migrate the theme...Not the whole WordPress install

Comment: @mevius i have added more pages and content aswell.

Answer (score 2):

I will walk you through this step by step.

1. Create a copy your production environment on your development environment.
2. You will need to export/import your production server MySql database via phpMyAdmin. For a good tutorial in how to do this, go to: https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204403864/export-and-import-mysql-databases
3. Using phpMyAdmin on your dev database, export all rows from every wp_ table, excluding the wp_posts table.
4. From your dev/production database, import all rows in to the appropriate tales.
5. Test your dev/production site for errors or problems.

It is likely that some of the rows in the wp_posts table has data not related to just Wordpress Posts. You will need to identify these as well by running a SQL query, such as:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type='some_id'
```

Breaking down the SQL query for you:
`[SELECT *]`  Select All
`[FROM wp_posts]`  From the table "wp_posts"
`[WHERE post_type='some_id']`  'some_id' is associated with a post type.

Themes, plugins and other functionality are often extended through:
`wp_posts table -> post_type='some_id'`.

The default value for Wordpress posts is:
`post_type='posts'`.

Rows within the wp_posts table that **DO NOT** have the
`post_type='posts'`
value should be migrated over to your production server.

**References:**
Wordpress Database:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description

MySql Select a Row Query:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_a_Row

Wordpress Database Diagram:
https://codex.wordpress.org/images/2/2a/WP3.9.4-ERD.png

Export and Import MySql
https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204403864/export-and-import-mysql-databases

Connecting to a Wordpress Database with wp-config.php
https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php

Answer (score 0):

If they are on the same host, you can change the database through the wp-config.

You have to change this settings:

> define('DB_NAME', 'dabname');
>
> define('DB_USER', 'dbuser);
>
> define('DB_PASSWORD', 'dbpass');
>
> define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

Comment: Yeah, I have tried this but for some reason it doesent work. Looks like the old site

Comment: Do you want the theme archives but no the database?